# "Show" en langage d'espions

Tags: jargon

Context is German spies organizing cover-up for an operation

> In spycraft, a “show” was both the secret operation and its cover-up.

Quite difficult to find this in french — if any equivalent exists.

Comment: Can you please give more details on what it is supposed to mean ?

Comment: Nothing more than that : it's exactly what is written here : a "show" is both the operation and the way to cover it up plausibly.

Comment: Just a thought, but it seems that by its very nature, a spy operation necessarily includes, from start to finish, both “the doing” part and the “cover-up/clandestine” part, meaning that while activities/operations in other fields might have to be called “the **whole** show” to fully cover the “start-to-finish” notion, in spy/tradecraft, the “whole” is omitted as redundant. So maybe looking for translations of English slang for “the **whole** show” (eg, the whole shebang) could lead to something like [tout] “le tralala/toutim/tremblement/bazaar.”

Comment: @PapaPoule I'm surprised about "toutim" and "tremblement" ? Where do you get it from ? I've never heard "toutim" at all, and never heard "tout le tremblement"

Comment: @Random I must admit I’m only familiar with “tralala” & “bazar” (spelled wrong in my 1st comment!) in this context. I found *[tout le] “toutim” et “tremblement”* among [these *Reverso in context* examples](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?q=the+whole+shebang&langFrom=en&langTo=fr&langTot=en-fr), where alliteration seems to be a common thread. Inspired by your comment, I just now found [“toutim” also mentioned here](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/14354/et-tout-le-toutim/) and [“tremblement” here](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/et-tout-le-tremblement.php).

Comment: “The Show” ([Major League Baseball](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=The%20Show)) and “The Big Dance” ([the NCAA basketball tournament/March Madness](http://www.waywordradio.org/big_dance/)) are sports jargon here in the US that might have some relevance to the “sport” of espionage in English, from which you could certainly get to clr’s "Le/un Spectacle" or perhaps even to [“La/une Grande Danse”](http://context.reverso.net/translation/english-french/%22The+show%2C%22+or...+or+%22the+big+dance%2C%22) for a less literal, more “encrypted” term for “the/a show” in French. cc:@Random

Comment: Can you provide evidence that the word show in English means what you say? I agree with Papa Poule, "the whole show" is slang but not just in "spycraft". In any situation where you are trying to create an illusion of something.

Answer (score 4):

Je pense qu'une traduction plus compréhensible serait "façade" ou "couverture".

En effet, ces mots désignent à la fois la mission de l'agent secret ainsi que sa couverture.

Il m'est difficile d'expliquer plus en profondeur mon raisonnement puisque ce sont des mots qui me sont venus instinctivement en lisant la phrase, et je doute de l'existence d'autres équivalents aussi "directs" (il y a bien sûr des traductions plus recherchées comme le salon/spectacle de cl-r).

Comment: "Couverture" est un assez bon équivalent, la différence étant qu'il évoque davantage la manière de masquer l'opération secrète (la mission) que celle-ci. Ca n'empêche pas pour un espion qui parle avec ses collègue de leur dire qu'il part deux mois en couverture/sous couverture à Los Angeles.

Comment: @AnneAunyme c'est pour cela que façade me semblait ^etre une bonne traduction, car ça évoque autant au niveau physique que ce qu'il peut se trouver autour du personnage (on utilise bien des expressions comme "sourire de façade")

Comment: couverture is cover in English

Answer (score 3):

La traduction de *[Reverso](http://www.reverso.net/translationresults.aspx?lang=FR&direction=anglais-francais)* traduit :

> Dans spycraft, *un spectacle* (*salon*) était tant opération secrète que son camouflage (dissimulation)."

En français, le *spectacle* dont on parle s'appelle une *mission (secrète)*.

Dans le langage codé des espions dont la mission doit rester inconnue aux yeux des autres, ils s'offrent en 'spectacle', jouent un rôle public qui dissimule leurs activités secrètes, ils utilisent donc un langage par eux seuls connu.

S'il doit signifier à un collègue qu'il est en mission, il ne peut le dire clairement, des oreilles indiscrètes pourraient en tirer partie.

On peut aussi entendre qu'il est en mission dans un *salon*, qui peut-être entendu comme

- un salon littéraire ou de rencontre privée  autour d'un même thème (en fait une entreprise ou une institution ennemie) où il peut aussi être agent double,
- comme une manifestation commerciale de grande envergure dans laquelle, sous couvert de démarches commerciales, il peut mener à bon terme ses 'enquêtes' sans être démasqué.

---

P.S. : *[tiombart](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/19247/848)* donne la traduction habituelle de "show".

*Couverture* peut être employée par des espions ou des journalistes ; on peut aussi utiliser le verbe ou le mot couvert :

> Quel événements *couvres-tu* en ce moment ?
>
> Sous *couvert* d'un reportage à Sydney, j'en profiterai pour filmer les kangourous ! (kangourous pouvant être ici le nom de code d'une cible à espionner, ou l'objectif du documentariste qui fera deux reportages en un seul déplacement).

Comment: Merci, intéressant. Ici, spycraft désigne le métier d'espion, pas le jeu…

Comment: "Spectacle" est effectivement la traduction de "show" mais il s'agit d'une traduction littérale. Je n'ai jamais vu dans aucun film d'espions l'un d'eux parler de sa couverture comme d'un "spectacle". A la rigueur on pourrait voir des gangster des années 90 utiliser ce mot pour désigner un braquage ou autre action de terrain, mais pas des espions.

Comment: @AnneAunyme J'ai dans la tête "Tu vas au spectacle" dit à quelqu'un qui partait aux renseignements chez un concurrent... réplique dont je n'arrive pas à retrouver l'origine. *Couverture* mentionné dans la réponse de 'tiombart' est mille fois plus courante.

Answer (score 1):

Je dois me répéter : la "couverture" n'est que la *moitié* du "show". L'autre moitié étant ce qui est couvert. L'ensemble correspond à ce "show".
"Façade" pourrait être une solution. 
"Montage" serait dans doute la moins mauvaise.